# How to push number in list

Tags: grails

I have a data like this,

```
params = [10, on]
```

I want to keep only int in list and I did like below,

```
def myList = []
params.each(){
  if( it != 'on'){
     myList.push(it)
  }
}
println myList
```

Buy I got the result like this

```
[1,0]
```

It's not be [10]

Comment: params = [10, on], what is the value of _on_ variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of the `params` entries that are integers you can be very concise in groovy:

```
def myList = params.findAll{it.isInteger()}
```

this code goes through `params` and evaluates the closure for each element and only if the evaluation returns `true`, the element is added to `myList`.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are printing for `params` and the one you are using for your `each` are not the same.  If you would have a list for param your code would work (even if `each` is the wrong tool here, use `findAll`).  E.g:

```
def params = [10, 'on']
assert params.findAll{ it!='on' } == [10]
```

But your `params` in your code is the String `10` (and not a list of the number 10 and the String `on`).  Since a string can be iterated to get each char, you get your wrong result.  E.g.:

```
assert '10'.collect()==['1','0']
```

PS: always use `findAll` to filter your data and `collect` to map them. `each` with some external var is cumbersome.